# Rspec controller spec with route including custom parameter

Tags: rspec, routes, controllers

routes
get '/foo/bar' => foo/bar#index {:custom_auth => [:admin]}

I have the route with custom_auth specified in config/routes.rb file.

While invoking index method from controller spec, it complains about route not found which works well without custom_auth parameter removed from routes config.

Is there a way to pass custom_auth while invoking the controller/action from controller spec ?

```
   describe Foo::BarsController do
     describe 'GET index' do
        get :index
        expect(response).to eq {}
      end
   end
```

config/routes.rb

```
get '/foo/bar', :to => 'foo/bar#index', :custom_auth => [:admin]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the required params in a params hash while invoking `get :index` request.

So, build a `params` hash and then pass that to the `get :index` call like this:

```
let(:admin) { double('admin') }
let(:custom_auth_params) { { :custom_auth => [:admin] } }
get :index, custom_auth_params
```